# Check for specific value/string in args of python exception

Tags: python-3.x, exception

In my python code, I am catching a specific exception using

```
except requests.HTTPError as ex:
```

printing ex.args shows following data

```
    {"code":400,"status":"Bad Request","timestamp":"2017-07-14T12:42:41+05:30",
"message":"Can not cancel order - 123123123123123",
"error":{"name":"Error","reason":"Can not cancel order - 170714000048253"}}
```

Is this ex.args some dictionary or string? I want to check for specific values like code and message once the exception is raised. How do I do it in best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ex.args` returns tuple with error json, you can parse it and use like this:

```
import json

data = json.loads(ex.args[0])

print(data['code'])
```

Comment: I got a error for json.loads 
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
        errorJson=json.loads(ex.args)
      File "C:\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 312, in loads
        s.__class__.__name__))
    TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'tuple'`

Comment: if `ex.args` returns tuple, then you have to get string message from that tuple which you have posted in your question.

Comment: yes. It was a tuple and extracted the json from it. Thanks. Can you edit your first answer so that I can revote it?

Comment: Done, not sure about error json index in tuple though :)

Comment: This is how I made it work
`msgDict=json.loads(ex.args[0])
code=msgDict['code']`